# Django: Cannot Add Clickable Link in the Template

Tags: python, django

I am a beginner in Django. I am building a Django app, named PhoneReview. It will store reviews related to the latest mobile phone. It will also display phone brands, along with the associated phone models. I have already created models for:

Brand – details on brand, such as, name, origin, manufacturing since, etc

Model – details on model, such as, model name, launch date, platform, etc

Review – review article on the mobile phone and date published, etc

Many-to-many relationship between Review and Model.

I also have created views for the following:

a. An index page that display all Brands available for mobile phone in the database

b. A phone model page that display model when a brand is selected.

c. A detail page when a model is selected that contain reviews and newslink

Now, I am facing a problem. I cannot put any clickable link that will redirect the phone brands, like Apple and Samsung, of brandlist.html web page, to their respective phone model page (phonemodel.html). Here is the screenshot:
[image]

Here are the codes of models.py inside "PhoneReview" folder.

```
from django.db import models
from django.template.defaultfilters import slugify

# Create your models here.
class Brand(models.Model):
    brand_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    origin = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    manufacturing_since = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.brand_name

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

class PhoneModel(models.Model):
    brand = models.ForeignKey(Brand, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    model_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    launch_date = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    platform = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.model_name

class Review(models.Model):
    phone_model = models.ManyToManyField(PhoneModel, related_name='reviews')
    review_article = models.TextField()
    date_published = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.review_article
```

Here are the codes of urls.py inside "PhoneReview" folder.

```
from . import views
from django.urls import path

urlpatterns = [
    path('index', views.BrandListView.as_view(), name='brandlist'),
    path('phonemodel/<int:pk>/', views.ModelView.as_view(), name='modellist'),
    path('details/<int:pk>/', views.ReviewView.as_view(), name='details'),
]
```

Here are the codes of views.py inside "PhoneReview" folder:

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import Brand, PhoneModel, Review


class BrandListView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/brandlist.html'
    context_object_name = 'all_brands'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Brand.objects.all()


class ModelView(generic.DetailView):
    model = PhoneModel
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/phonemodel.html'

class ReviewView(generic.DetailView):
    model = Review
    template_name = 'PhoneReview/details.html'
```

Here are the codes of apps.py inside "PhoneReview" folder:

```
from django.apps import AppConfig


class PhonereviewConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'PhoneReview'
```

Here are the codes of phonemodel.html. The page can be accessed by going through http://127.0.0.1:8000/phonemodel/1/ in the browser.

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Phone Model Page
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Phone Model Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the phone model</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</li>
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

Here are the codes of brandlist.html. The web page can be accessed by going to http://127.0.0.1:8000/index in the browser.

```
{% extends 'PhoneReview/base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block title%}
Brand List
{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<!--Page content-->
<h1>This is Brand List Page</h1>
<h2>Here is the list of the brands</h2>
    <ul>
        {% for brand in all_brands %}
            <li>{{ brand.brand_name }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
<img src="{% static "images/brandlist.jpg" %}" alt="Super Mario Odyssey" /> <!-- New line -->
{% endblock %}
```

I tried modifying `<li>{{ brand.brand_name }}</li>`to `<li><a href = "{% url 'phonemodel:modellist' brand.id %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>` . But the code doesn't work.

What should I do?

**Update 1:** I can't view the brandlist.html page when I add `<li><a href = "{% url 'phonemodel:modellist' brand.id %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>`. I get an error on http://127.0.0.1:8000/index. It says 'phonemodel' is not a registered namespace

**Update 2:** I have managed to fix the issue. I changed the code to `<li><a href = "{% url 'modellist' brand.id %}">{{ brand.brand_name }}</a></li>`. Thanks to @LinhNguyen for giving me the idea.

Comment: Your note there looks like what I was going to recommend, although you need to close your <a> tag. You need to know what doesn't work so use your browser's Inspect mode to look at what it has made of the html it received.  If it has ignored the <a> tag for some reason, you might out about find it there.

Comment: seem like you didn't close your a tag with `</a>`

Comment: @Atcrank I have closed it now. However, the problem is not fixed.

Comment: @LinhNguyen I have closed the tag. But it doesn't fix the issue.

Comment: can you  right click and on the link and right click to see what the html it output ?

Comment: @LinhNguyen I can't view the page when I add <li><a href = "{% url 'phonemodel:modellist' brand.id %}">{{ phonemodel.model_name }}</a></li>. I get an error. It says 'phonemodel' is not a registered namespace

Comment: you don't need `phonemodel:` in your `"{% url 'phonemodel:modellist' brand.id %}"` because you already declared the url name as `modellist` in your urls.py

Comment: Yes. You are right. However, after doing that, the brand names, like Apple and Samsung, were not being displayed. So, I changed the code to `<li><a href = "{% url 'modellist' brand.id %}">{{ brand.brand_name }}</a></li>`. Then it fixes the issue completely.

Comment: @LinhNguyen You can add your reply in the answer. Once added, I will choose it as the right answer. In the meantime, would you please take a look at this question. I am facing adding clickable link in the second template. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58742143/django-problem-with-adding-clickable-link-in-the-second-template

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to close your a tag  and since you already declared your url name in urls.py so no need to add the app name before the url

```
<a href = "{% url 'modellist' brand.id %}">{{ brand.brand_name }}</a>
```